# Query Failed Error: Unexpected. Please try again. Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am unable to execute a simple select query (`select * from [<DatasetName>.<TableName>] LIMIT 1000`) with Google BigQuery. It is giving me below error:

```
Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: job_51MSM2uo1vE5QomZA8Sv_RUE7M8
```

The table contains around 10 records. I am able to execute queries on other tables.

Job Id is - job_51MSM2uo1vE5QomZA8Sv_RUE7M8.

Comment: This looks to be related to querying tables with streaming inserts. We're investigating.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a temporary issue where we were seeing timeouts when querying tables that had been inserted to recently via streaming insert (tabledata.insertall()). We're currently addressing the underlying issue, but it should be working now. Please ping this thread if you see it again.